# What are the differences between Vinci and Small World?

Tags: small-world, vinci

Small World has been described as a re-implementation of Vinci, but I've heard that there are some non-trivial differences.  How do these two games differ in terms of rules/mechanics and feel of play?  (I'm not concerned with the change from Europe to a fantasy map *unless* it affects play.)

I'm familiar with Vinci but have never played Small World.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an excellent comparison of the two [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/398713/vinci-vs-small-world-the-definitive-guide-with-pic).  Some highlights:

- Vinci has one big set of powers and you draw two for each race.  Small World splits them into Race Powers and Abilities, preventing some combinations from occurring.
- Vinci charges you two points for each race you skip over, Small World only 1.  This modifies the dynamics of which races you might choose.
- The end game conditions in Vinci are reaching a certain number of points, making the length variable.  Small World has a fixed number of turns based on number of players.
- Small World has different maps for different numbers of players, and you always get the same number of tokens for a race/power combo.  Vinci only had one map, but varied the number of tokens a power combo started with based on the number of players.
- Small World adds a reinforcement dice which gives you a random chance to take over a single province that you wouldn't be able to conquer normally at the end of your turn.